# Fuzzy string matching using elasticsearchand return the edit distance or similarity score

Tags: elasticsearch, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to do a match query with fuzzy results and order the results based on edit distance. However elasticsearch returns a relevance score (_score) which is based on frequency and each query. Is there anyway to obtain only the edit distance from elasticsearch. Also will writing my own custom function to calculate the edit distance slow down the search?

Comment: Can you post a bit more exemplified details of what you are trying to do, what doesn't work and what are the expected results.

Comment: 'For example lets say i'm searching by name in a document that contains a bunch of fields about the person. Elastic-search returns the relevance score based on a bunch of factors including frequency etc. I want elastic-search to return it based only on the name. 

To be specific, I search for ABCD it returns ABCD with edit distance 0, ABCE edit distance 1, ADCB, edit distance 1 etc. I know a match with fuzzy query can give me desired results. However, i want to use elasticsearch to return the edit distance as well. Or some metric to quantify how different the strings are.

Comment: A simple solution might be the following: A fuzzy query with ES will get the correct ordering based on edit distance. Then to compute the edit distance you can do that as a post-processing step.

Comment: But fuzzy query already scores my document based on a string match, doing the scoring outside would only be an unnecessary step right?

Comment: Fuzzy match query was not designed to be used that way. The best action you can take is to calculate the string edit distance on the application level after elasticsearch returns. This article will help you understand more https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html